# Processing sketch on web: different behaviours on different computers, same browser

Tags: processing, processing.js

I have 3 processing sketches on a webpage (150.146.65.246).
According to the computer where I open the page, I have different behaviours:
on some computer, once the page is opened the sketches are erroneously reinitialised again and again, as if the page was continuously refreshed.  On other computer, the sketches are correctly initialised only once, when the page is opened.
The browsers tested are Firefox  and Chrome.

I'm starting to think it dependes on some Browser settings, do you have any idea?

Comment: The issue maybe comes from to the implementation of processing.js

Comment: Can you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a link to the page in question, or a jsfiddle?

Comment: Hi Kevin. I'll work on a MCVE as requested. In the meanwhile the link to the page is 150.146.65.246   You'll see in the first sketch (called "Simculture") a coloured circle. If sketch is correctly visualised, it will not change colour and position, otherwise it will be continuously reinitialised with new color and position.